# C# HttpRequest sequence succeeds while running Fiddler, but otherwise fails

Tags: httprequest, fiddler

Background: I'm trying to log into an HTTPS site with my valid credentials, navigate to a page that has a frequently updated list, and then scrape the list.
I was using code someone else wrote, which worked until a few weeks ago.  I am new to this, but even i can see that the code was not very good, so i am trying to rewrite.

First I log into the site and create an tunnel.  Then I move to the page where my list is and grab the list, etc.

Here's what's weird.  The login fails every time, until I turn on Fiddler.  With Fiddler running it succeeds every time.

Any idea about why this would happen and how to fix?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

For anyone who finds themselves in the same situation (I've seen a number of posting of similar questions - but the answers hadn't worked for me, so I expect I am not alone), I eventually saw that I needed to set the security protocol to TLS.  The specific syntax I used was:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

The setting needs to be specified before the Httpwebrequest get or post event occurs.

If you have a similar problem, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had an invalid "User-Agent" header. It contained invalid characters (ä, ö, ü).